# Win10: How to prevent OpenVPN connect from connecting at startup?

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

Using the official OpenVPN Connect client version 2.7.1.104 on Windows 10, and I cannot keep it from automatically connecting to the VPN on login.

Per the official [instructions](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/setting-your-client-to-automatically-connect-to-your-vpn-when-your-computer-starts/),

> To disable autoconnect on Windows boot up you simply need to
>   right-click on the tray icon and select disconnect.

But this does not work. The next time I boot the system, it automatically connects.

How can I prevent this?

(Note: I am a Linux user with only casual familiarity with Windows 10, so please be explicit. I am attempting to help a family member connect to a VPN network using their Windows 10 system. They do not wish to have the VPN connected by default)

Comment: What I do with all VPN Applications is prevent them from starting with Windows.  Go to VPN preferences or Windows Startup Programs (Task Manager) and turn "Start with Windows" OFF.  Restart, make sure it did not start and then put an icon on your desktop to start it and connect as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open Services by clicking Windows+R and typing `services.msc`.Then look for OpenVPN Service and make sure its startup type is set to manual. This shall solve your problem.

Comment: This did it, thanks.  I wish that there was an easier way for my family member to start it other than going into `services.msc` but this all just reminds me why I left Windows.

Comment: No, you are not supposed to start from ```services.msc```. Its just to stop it at startup. To start, you can use its own GUI.

Comment: It threw an error and didn't work when I started it that way. It would only work if I started it through the services app.